# Move mysql configuration to JNDI

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I have a java-ee webapp using JSF and we have a database component inside the app

#### Creds

In my code we have the database credentials defined as:

```
String url = "jdbc://mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true";
String user = "root";
String pwd = "P@ssw0rd";
```

#### Connection

Then for the db connection itself is **JDBC** which I'm thinking might be a problem

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MysqlJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

 // some other random code
try {
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
  System.out.println("[MYSQL]\tSUCCESS - Connected to [" + url + "] as user: " + user);
  return;
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("[MYSQL]\tFAILURE - Could not connect to [" + url + "] as user: " + user);
  System.out.println("[MYSQL]\t" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

#### JNDI

I don't fully understand how JDNI works but as I understand you define a resource externally and at runtime or startup of a web application it will read the data from somewhere and insert it into the applications.  I'm using **Tomcat** and I was wondering is there a way to do something that would allow me to populate my database credentials via the **JNDI** information.

If this is not possible do I have to define my entire database connection externally and re-write all my internal code to somehow use it?

Any code examples would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect and easy-to-follow guide to configure external db resource via JNDI for Tomcat: [link](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/) and this one [link](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/configuring-jndi-datasource-for-database-connection-pooling-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Another reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html
... scroll down to JDBC DataSources.